Reducing the sunflower problem to the Ramsey problem, best bound?
Suppose you have a family $F$ of sets each of size $l$. How large does $|F|$ have to be for $F$ to necessarily contain (as a subfamily) a sunflower with r petals?
Let the sunflower number $S(r, l)$ be the smallest $|F|$ satisfying the above statement. The sunflower lemma says that $S(r, l) \leq l!(r - 1)^l$.
What is the best upper bound can we can get for $S(r, l)$ by reduction to Ramsey's Theorem? Ramsey's theorem follows:
Let the Ramsey Number $R(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k)$ be the smallest number such that any $k$ coloring of the complete graph on $R(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k)$ vertices contains as a subgraph a monochromatic clique of color $i$ and size $\geq r_i$, for some $i \in [k]$. Then $R(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k)$ is finite.
There are bounds known for both $S(r, l)$ and $R(r_1, \ldots, r_k)$. I am looking for a bound on the sunflower problem by $\textit{reduction}$ to the Ramsey problem.
The best bound I can get on $S(r, l)$ by reduction to $R(r_1, \ldots, r_l)$ is the following:
Suppose you have a $l$-uniform family $F$. Consider a complete graph $G$ with $|F|$ vertices. Identify the set of vertices of $G$ with $F$ and color the edge $A, B$ with color $|A \cap B|$. Clearly, this is an $l$ coloring of $G$. Let $M_i = (r - 2)\binom{l}{i} + 2$ for $0 \leq i \leq l - 1$. Then I claim that if $|F| \geq R(M_0, M_1, \ldots, M_{l - 1})$, $F$ contains a sunflower with $r$ petals. This is easily proved using pigeonhole.

One way to improve this would of course be to improve the bound for $M_i$ without changing the rest of the proof whatsoever. Interestingly enough, it seems to be tight at low values of $r$ and $l$. I found examples of set systems of $(r-2)\binom{l}{i}+1$ sets for $r=2$ and $r= 3,l\leq 5$ with no sunflower with $r$ petals except in the particular case of $l=5,i=3$, where the bound is not tight for the first time. In particular, it is tight for all $l$ if $r=3$ and $i=1$ or $l-1$.

A related, but not quite equivalent question is whether an $i-(n,l,r-1)$-design exists for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Unfortunately, Ramsey numbers are huge, especially multicolor, see, for instance, this my answer. Even when we consider $R(s,s)$, where $s$ is not bigger than at least two of $M_i$'s for nonnegative integer $i\le l-1$, we obtain that $$R(s,s)\geq (1+o(1)){\frac {s}{{\sqrt {2}}e}}2^{s/2}.$$
Also in 1947, Erdős gave a simple probabilistic proof that $R(s,s)>2^{s/2}$.
We can estimate $M_i$'s using bounds and asymptotic formulas for binomial coefficients.
If $i=l/2$ then ${l\choose i}\approx \frac{2^{l-1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi l}}\approx 2^\ell$.
Plugging $r2^\ell$ as $s$, we obtain
$$R(s,s)>2^{r2^{\ell-1}}.$$
